# Greenplum pxf - select from external table - invalid configuration

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, parquet, greenplum

I have a greenplum database up and running and parquet files stored in hdfs at `/user/hadoopuser/raw/`
I installed and launched pxf and created external table with:

```
create external table requests(id bigint, full_name text, req_date timestamp)
location('pxf://user/hadoopuser/raw?PROFILE=hdfs:parquet') format 'CUSTOM' (formatter='pxfwritable_import')
```

But when I try to access data with `select * from requests` I get the following error:

```
[08000] ERROR: PXF server error : invalid configuration for server 'default' (seg0 slice1 10.0.2.20:6000 pid=18636) Hint: Configure a valid value for 'pxf.fs.basePath' property for server 'default' to access the filesystem.
```

pxf-service.log only contains

```
java.io.IOException: org.greenplum.pxf.api.error.PxfRuntimeException: invalid configuration for server 'default'
```

What is the valid value for `pxf.fs.basePath`, where do I set it and why is this error happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PXF stores configuration for external data sources (e.g., "servers") in either `$PXF_HOME/servers/` (the default) or `$PXF_BASE/servers`. Unless you have relocated `$PXF_BASE` (see [Relocating `$PXF_BASE`](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tanzu-Greenplum-Platform-Extension-Framework/6.3/tanzu-greenplum-platform-extension-framework/GUID-about_pxf_dir.html?hWord=N4IghgNiBcIAoA0BiB9AQgQQMoFEQF8g#movebase) in the docs), it will be stored in `$PXF_HOME` which is `/usr/local/pxf-gp<GPDB-major-version>`.

In the `$PXF_HOME/servers` directory, there should be one directory per external data source and there typically is called `default/`. For access HDFS, this directory should contain:

1. a copy of hdfs-site.xml
2. a copy of core-site.xml
3. a copy of pxf-site.xml (see `$PXF_HOME/templates`)

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot, I've put the required copies to my $PXF_BASE/servers/default and changed impersonating in pxf-site.xml to false, now I can select from my hdfs directory with no trouble